# How to generate new array of objects from existing array of objects using lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

Can someone help me generate a new array of objects from an existing one using lodash? I've been trying a combination of `_.zipObject and map` but to no avail... basically, I have an array of objects like:

```
const names = [
  {
    first_name: 'nedd',
    given_name: 'cersei'
  },
  {
    first_name: 'tyrion',
    given_name: 'tywin'
  }
]
```

However, I want it to look like:

```
[
  {
    name: 'nedd'
  },
  {
    name: 'cersei'
  },
  {
    name: 'tyrion'
  },
  {
    name: 'tywin'
  },
]
```

I have tried various iterations of:

`const newArray = _.zipObject( names, _.fill( Array(names.length), {name: ['first_name' || 'given_name']} ) );`

But without any luck... can someone help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work:

```
_.flatMap(names, (n)=> [{name: n.first_name}, {name: n.given_name}]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `_.flatMap` combined with `_.map`:

```
_.flatMap(names, (nameObj) => _.map(nameObj, (objVal) => { return { name: objVal }; }));
```